# Не могу найти в android studio библиотеку rxkotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

хочу добавить `implementation`, чтобы использовать rxkotlin для проекта, но его нет в списке. пишу `*rxkotlin*` - ничего. то есть, только вот это.
[image: picture]

Comment: я так понял, что нужно заходить на github и смотреть какая там версия. и вписывать её в gradle в implementation.

Comment: Там странная поисковая система - проще, как вы догадались, найти в сети саму библиотеку и обычно прямо на главной странице указано как её добавить в проект. Тем более что не все библиотеки публикуются в bintray или maven и бывает нужно добавлять адрес репозитория или клонировать и подключать локально.

Answer (score 0):

В build.gradle (:app) в строке `dependencies` впишите `implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxkotlin:3.x.x")`, где x - актуальная версия, например, `implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxkotlin:3.0.0")`